# diificulty in posting video on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an app in which i want to paste video on facebook.But whenever i try,i am getting is exception:

```
08-26 14:56:41.311: D/Facebook-Example(520): Response: {"error":{"message":"(#351) Video file was corrupt or invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":351}}
08-26 14:56:41.366: W/Facebook-Example(520): Facebook Error: (#351) Video file was corrupt or invalid
```

This is the code:

```
 mUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                byte[] data = null;
                AssetFileDescriptor fileDesc = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                R.raw.baba);
                String dataPath =  fileDesc.toString();//"android.resource://com.facebook.android/raw/movie";
                String dataMsg = "Your video description here.";
                String dataName = "baba.wav";

                Bundle param;
                AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                InputStream is ;
                try 
                {
                        is = fileDesc.createInputStream();
                    if(is != null)
                    data = readBytes(is);
                    param = new Bundle();
                    param.putString("message", dataMsg);
                    param.putString("filename", dataName);
                    param.putByteArray("video", data);
                    mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new SampleRequestListener(), null);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
        });
        mUploadButton.setVisibility(mFacebook.isSessionValid() ?
                View.VISIBLE :
                View.INVISIBLE);
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks.

Comment: is baba.wav a video file ? i suppose it is not anyway if you want to go straight to upload a video i suggest to refer this facebook link
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/
get token from Facebook Android , and do upload by your self

Comment: even i have tried the mp4 and 3gp file i am getting the same error.

Comment: As per Graph API documention video should be uploaded to https://graph-video.facebook.com/
while the default graph endpoint is https://graph.facebook.com/

Said that ,if  i was you i would verify where AsyncFacebookRunner is posting to

Comment: Sir can u please tell me how to check that on which site i am posting .

Comment: you can install some network trace tool as wireshark and analyze network  traffic ... but it requires sometime to install and understand how to ... so be aware  it will NOT resolve the problem by itself, just give you some additional info on what is going on at http level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you authenticated in your app? if not facebook will throw an error. You need an authentication id to be able to post on facebook.

Comment: Sir can you please explain the concept of authenticity.

Comment: Facebook system needs to identify your app before you do anything to their system. You go there and create an app and they will give you an authentication number of your app. Whenever you send date you must send that number along.Facebook verify whether it does exist.If it does facebook let you do whatever you wanna do if it does not facebook throws an error.

Comment: yes sir,i have created the facebook app id and authenticated me before asking this question itself.

Comment: I think this is not the problem sir.

Comment: 'file was corrupt or invalid' is not the real issue since you know the file does exist and is not corrupt. I would check the code logic especially that 'AsyncFacebookRunner' I think that is where is likely to be the problem.I am trying to give you ideas I don't assume anything.

Comment: There may be also a problem of whitelist blacklist issue.Before a domain to have an swf on facebook like a sound player to appear on facebook that domain must be whitelisted.One need to write to them and ask them to put the domain on the whitelist.I don't know whether that is the same issue here.